# menuToggle not working on mobile devices but working on Desktop when adding my AngularJS module

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add autosuggestion using AngularJS material library. It's working fine for me now. But now the problem is when i'm adding **ng-App="MyApp2"** then my **menuToggle** button is not working in mobile device only but it's working fine in desktop.
If i'm adding **[ng-App=""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BiF9.jpg)** then also it's working fine but then obviously autosuggestion feature will stopped working.

I got stuck into this issue. Please help me...
Thank in advance.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Booking | web</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />        
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.5/angular-material.css'>
        <style>
            input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ff0000;
            }

            input, select, textarea {
            color: Black;
            font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15pt;
            font-weight: 400;
            letter-spacing: 0.075em;
            line-height: 1.65em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Page Wrapper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header" class="alt">
                            <h1><a href="index.php">web</a></h1>
                            <nav id="nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="special">
                                        <a href="#menu" class="menuToggle"><span>Menu</span></a>
                                        <div id="menu">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="price_calculator.php">Start Booking</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="about_us.php">About Us</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="enquiry.php">Enquiry</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                    </header>

                <!-- Main -->
                    <article id="main">
                        <header>
                            <h2>Price Calculator</h2>
                            <p>Calculate your trip cost </p>
                        </header>
                        <section id="three" class="wrapper style3 special">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <section  ng-controller="DCtrl as ctrl"  ng-app="MyApp2" ng-cloak>
                                     <form method="post" action="fare.php"  name="searchForm">
                                        <div class="row uniform">
                                                <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)" style="width:100%">
                                                    <md-autocomplete  md-input-name="origin" ng-disabled="true" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItemO"  md-search-text="ctrl.searchTextO" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearchO(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" placeholder="From: Varanasi" >
                                                    </md-autocomplete>  
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)" style="width:100%; ">                                             
                                                    <md-autocomplete required="" flex="" md-input-name="destination" md-input-minlength="l" md-input-maxlength="18"         md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"  md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"     md-item-text="item.display" md-require-match="" placeholder="Destination City" >
                                                        <md-item-template>
                                                            <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
                                                        </md-item-template>
                                                        <md-not-found>
                                                            No matches found.
                                                        </md-not-found>
                                                    </md-autocomplete>
                                                    <div ng-messages="searchForm.destination.$error" ng-if="searchForm.destination.$touched">
                                                        <div ng-message="required" style="color:#ff0000;">You <b style="color:#ff0000;">must</b> have a destination.</div>
                                                        <div ng-message="md-require-match" style="color:#ff0000;">Please select an existing city.</div>
                                                        <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
                                                        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
                                                    </div>  
                                                </div>                                              
                                                <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)" style="width:100%">
                                                    <ul class="actions vertical">
                                                        <li><input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="special"
                                                            ng-disabled="searchForm.destination.$untouched || searchForm.destination.$invalid" />
                                                        </li>                                                       
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>                                     
                                </section>                          
                            </div>
                        </section>                          
                    </article>

                <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                        <ul class="icons">
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/justcaritdotcom/" target="_blank" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope-o"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="copyright">
                            <li>&copy; Made with <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#cc0052;"></i> for <a href="index.php">web</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </footer>
        </div>



            <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
            <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js'></script>
            <script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.5/angular-material.js'></script>

            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

            <script>
                    (function () {
                          'use strict';
                          angular
                              .module('MyApp2',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
                              .controller('DCtrl', DCtrl);

                          function DCtrl ($timeout, $q) {
                            var self = this;

                            self.states        = loadAll();
                            self.selectedItem  = null;
                            self.searchText    = null;
                            self.querySearch   = querySearch;

                            function querySearch (query) {
                              var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states;
                              var deferred = $q.defer();
                              $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
                              return deferred.promise;
                            }

                        function loadAll() {
                          var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
                                  Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
                                  Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
                                  Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
                                  North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
                                  South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
                                  Wisconsin, Wyoming';

                          return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
                            return {
                              value: state.toLowerCase(),
                              display: state
                            };
                          });
                        }

                        function createFilterFor(query) {
                          var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

                          return function filterFn(state) {
                            return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
                          };

                        }
                      }
                    })();

            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you remove like [ng-App=""] then obviously angular fails because there is no app defined and obviously any other functionalaties will work which doesnt belong to angular. You need to watch both of the functionalities should work in combination.

Anyway your code works fine just dont remove **ng-app name**. Figure out how to do menu toggle without affecting the above.

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=DCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at VM7124 angular.min.js:6
at qb (VM7124 angular.min.js:23)
at Pa (VM7124 angular.min.js:23)
at VM7124 angular.min.js:89
at O (VM7124 angular.min.js:72)
at n (VM7124 angular.min.js:64)
at g (VM7124 angular.min.js:58)
at VM7124 angular.min.js:57
at VM7124 angular.min.js:21
at n.$eval (VM7124 angular.min.js:144)
```

Comment: But Sunil, that's what i'm asking for.. i'm not able to find the way.. please help me